# Изучаю админ панель Laravel NOVA. Хочу отобразить название категории в списке всех постов, как на рисунке.

Tags: laravel

**Как обратится к связующей таблице category_post и отобразить в списке постов, название всех категорий у данного поста?**

[image: отобразить категории в списке всех постов]
структура БД такова(многие посты имеют многие категории)

Post:id,image,title,fulltext

Categories: id, name, is_active

Category_post: post_id, category_id

Мне кажется нужно как-то обработать это поле ( **Text::make('categories'),**) в nova/post.php

```
    public function fields(Request $request){
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('title')->rules(['required']),
            Trix::make('announce')->rules(['required']),
            Trix::make('fulltext')->rules(['required']),
            DateTime::make('нач. публикации','publish_at')->hideFromIndex()->rules('after_or_equal:сегодня'), // название поля: publish_at
            DateTime::make('конец публикации','publish_until')->hideFromIndex()->rules('after_or_equal:публиковать_до'),


           Text::make('categories'),

            /*
           BelongsToMany::make('Categories')->fields(function(){
              return[ Text::make('Categories')];
    }),
*/
            BelongsToMany::make('Categories')->rules(['required']),
            BelongsTo::make('User')->rules(['required']),
            BelongsToMany::make('Tags'),
            Text::make('keywords')->hideFromIndex(),
            Text::make('description')->hideFromIndex()
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Что интересно то дальше при редактировании статьи все отлично работает - и хорошо подставляются категории к выбранному посту. Но в виде ПРОСТО ОТОБРАЗИТЬ ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ:  Из документации - загрузить отношение и получить доступ к его данным не получается. 

public static $ with = ['user'];
открытые поля функций (Request $ request) 
{ 
    return [ 
        Text :: make ('User', 'user.name'), 
    ]; 
} 

Хотя JSON данные вижу:

Comment: [ { "id": 2, "name": "Разработка", "slug": "razrabotka", "is_active": 1, "created_at": "2019-01-02 17:21:55", "updated_at": "2019-01-02 17:21:55", "deleted_at": null, "pivot": { "post_id": 12, "category_id": 2 } }, { "id": 4, "name": "Путешествия", "slug": "puteshestviya", "is_active": 1, "created_at": "2019-01-02 17:21:55", "updated_at": "2019-01-02 17:21:55", "deleted_at": null, "pivot": { "post_id": 12, "category_id": 4 } } ]